# No Managed Heap data was collected. This feature requires .NET v4.5 or greater

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio 2019 with framework 5.0 Performance Profiler to find memory leaks in an ASP.NET Core Web API application.
i have ticked "memory usage" checkbox.
when i click on stop collection button i am getting No Managed Heap data was collected. This feature requires .NET v4.5 or greater error.
Any clue on how I could get this thing working?

i have tried to run the memory usage multiple times but getting the same error.

Comment: Please mention what you mean by framework 5.0 performance profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Memory leaks are rare in .NET.

If you're sure you want to look at "memory usage" (as opposed to ".NET Object Allocation Tracking"), click the cog wheel next to the memory checkbox and enable the option "Enable interop heap profiling with snapshots".

You can then click the "Take Snapshot" button during profiling.

Alternatively, if you are interested in managed memory usage, check ".NET Object Allocation Tracking" instead.