# Memory profiling in Visual Studio empty result set

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, memory-profiling

I am using Visual Studio 2022 memory profiling to profile an ASP.NET Core application. The debugging session gets started by clicking the "Start" button, the real time memory chart gets updated. However, when I click "Stop Collection" button, the rendered result set is empty, showing no memory objects (screenshot attached). What could be the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76270896/no-managed-heap-data-was-collected-this-feature-requires-net-v4-5-or-greater/76271032#76271032

Comment: It turns out I forgot to take a snapshot, the list shows snapshots taken during a debugging session.